# How does Unicode conversion to ASCII know to map Ł to L

Tags: unicode, unicode-normalization

I was surprised to find that no Unicode normalization of the `Ł` character maps it to something like `L + combining stroke`. That was my best explanation to understand why `Ł` to get mapped to `L` rather than `?` when converting from a Unicode-capable encoding to ASCII or a code page that doesn't have the `Ł` character. How does it work otherwise? Does the standard define fallback characters?

Comment: I don't think Unicode provides any resources for mappings like `Ł` → `L`, `ø` → `o` etc., which aren't covered by Unicode normalization. ASCII-fication tools like [UniDecode](http://p3rl.org/Text::Unidecode) use their own hand-crafted tables.

Comment: I've seen this happen with a Windows program that would likely be using `WideStringToMultiByte`, so maybe the answer lies outside of the Unicode standard.

Comment: This is not a matter of *normalization* but rather of *transliteration*. And yes, the Unicode standard DOES define transliterations for many Unicode characters.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, if you can make that an answer with some reference links, I'll accept it.

Comment: When you say “converting from a Unicode-capable encoding to ASCII”, where do you see that conversion happening in practice?

Comment: For example, in a console program outputting the slashed L character but it showing up as an L in the console.